# Firebase in app messaging is not working in my react native project. Anyone having the same issue?

Tags: firebase, react-native, firebase-in-app-messaging

I'm getting push notification messages without any problem, but I'm having trouble with the in app message, my firebase versions are as follows[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7rRNq.png)
I did all the installations according to the documentation.But I don't know why it's not working
react native version 0.64.4

I tried to install the latest version of firebase but it still didn't work

package.json

```js
 "@react-native-firebase/analytics": "14.0.0",
    "@react-native-firebase/app": "14.0.0",
    "@react-native-firebase/crashlytics": "14.0.0",
    "@react-native-firebase/in-app-messaging": "14.0.0",
    "@react-native-firebase/messaging": "14.0.0"
```

inside my app js file the code is like this

```js
async()=> {
    async function bootstrap() {
      await firebase.inAppMessaging().setMessagesDisplaySuppressed(true);
    }
    
    async function onSetup(user) {
      await setupUser(user);
      firebase.inAppMessaging().setMessagesDisplaySuppressed(false);
    }
    
    await bootstrap();
    await onSetup();    
  }
```

Comment: add code where you try to work with message

Comment: async()=> {
    async function bootstrap() {
      await firebase.inAppMessaging().setMessagesDisplaySuppressed(true);
    }
    
    async function onSetup(user) {
      await setupUser(user);
      firebase.inAppMessaging().setMessagesDisplaySuppressed(false);
    }
    
    await bootstrap();
    await onSetup();    
  }

Comment: I tried these lines in my app.js file

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue just follow the instruction as following

1. Go to google console and select the project that you created at firbase console and just search for **in-app messaging API** enable the api for your project.
   Here is the link https://console.cloud.google.com/

Hope you this will fix your issue.

Enjoy!!

Comment: After 8 month, found this solution and it works thx

Answer (score -1):

Probably you need to use this package https://github.com/invertase/react-native-firebase/tree/main/packages/in-app-messaging

An example of usage is here:

https://rnfirebase.io/in-app-messaging/usage#main

Also please use version ^16 of libraries for Firebase

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I have done all the installations but I cannot view the in app message.

Comment: This would be a better answer if you demonstrated the code from the links. If the links were to ever go offline your answer would then become useless.

Comment: @fahriyezeynepçakır have you tried the last version of the libraries 16.4.6?

Comment: @KirillNovikov I upgraded firebase to the latest updated version, but I still can't get a positive result. I did the steps in the documentation one by one. I updated my pods, but I still can't display the message on my device.

Comment: @fahriyezeynepçakır add error handling for your async calls because a lot of async functions without try catch